# Cannot update the pgadmin table colum through python

Tags: python, sql, pgadmin

I want to update the PGadmin 4 table call infomration_3g colum 'geom' through python.
Below is my code. I found a Syntax error called"invaild syntax". The error shulde be in the table column "Easting","Northing". But run the sql in PGadmin4. It is ok to update the table.
Can anyone can help?

```
import os
import csv
import psycopg2
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import ftplib
conn = psycopg2.connect (host="xxxx", database="xxx", user="xxx" 
,password="xxx", port="xxx")

update_gpis="UPDATE information_3g SET geom = 
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint("Easting","Northing"),2326)"

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(update_gpis)
cursor.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint("Easting","Northing"),2326) Is this the value that you need to have in geom field?

Comment: it problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: Add it as an answer so that others will be benefited from it